# how to align d3 graph x axis tick label with the lower end of y axis?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, alignment, axis-labels

Could some one please help with d3 ticks alignment?

I want the x axis ticks label in the screenshot below to be aligned to bottom location (-2.00) in this case. I have tried quite a few options, but could not figure out.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

My code is given at the bottom.

[image]

```html
const xScale = d3
                    .scaleLinear()
                    .domain([
                      data && data[0] ? Math.min(...data[0].items.map(d => d.hour)) : 0,
                      data && data[0] ? Math.max(...data[0].items.map(d => d.hour)) : 0
                    ])
                    .range([0, width]);

    const yScale = d3
                    .scaleLinear()
                    .domain([
                      data && data[0] ? getDataYMin() - 2 * (Math.ceil(Math.abs(getDataYMin())/10)) : 0,
                      data && data[0] ? getDataYMax() + 4 * (Math.ceil(getDataYMax()/10)): 0
                    ]).range([height, 0]);

    const svgEl = d3.select(svgRef.current);
    svgEl.selectAll("*").remove(); // Clear svg content before adding new elements
    const svg = svgEl
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
    
      // Add X grid lines with labels
    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(24).tickSize(-height + margin.bottom).tickPadding(10);
    const xAxisGroup = svg.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height - margin.bottom})`).call(xAxis);
    xAxisGroup.select(".domain").remove();
    xAxisGroup.selectAll(".tick:first-of-type line").attr("class", "axis_bar").attr("stroke", "black");
    xAxisGroup.selectAll(".tick:not(:first-of-type) line").attr("class", "axis_y_tick").attr("stroke", "rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.5)").style("stroke-dasharray", "5 5");
    xAxisGroup.selectAll("text").attr("opacity", 0.5).attr("color", "black").attr("font-size", "0.75rem");

    // Add Y grid lines with labels
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(10).tickSize(-width).tickFormat(d3.format(".2f"));
    const yAxisGroup = svg.append("g").call(yAxis);
    yAxisGroup.select(".domain").remove();
    yAxisGroup.selectAll(".tick:first-of-type line").attr("class", "axis_bar").attr("stroke", "black");
    yAxisGroup.selectAll(".tick:not(:first-of-type) line").attr("class", "axis_y_tick").attr("stroke", "rgba(155, 155, 155, 0.5)").style("stroke-dasharray", "5 5");
    yAxisGroup.selectAll("text").attr("opacity", 0.5).attr("color", "black").attr("font-size", "0.75rem");
```

The dimensions are defined constants and are passed through property to the chart component (this is a React application)

```html
const marginValue: Margin = {
    top: 30,
      right: 30,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 60
  };

  const dimensionsInput : Dimensions = {
    width: 1040,
    height: 400,
    margin: marginValue
  };
```

Comment: You have to show us how `height` is defined (regarding the SVG height and the `margin` object).

Comment: Thank you for your time and help Gerardo! I have updated my post above